# Python socket server share data with another class

Tags: python, sockets

I am using python thread to collect data on a serial port and write data to a database. 
what i need to do now, is, instead of writing the output to a terminal, write it to a socket that any client can connect to and read.

i have a function

```
def write_to_viewer(self, data):
    code to make data human readable
    print data
```

but what i need is instead of printing, to write this to a socket server, so that any time new data is processed, it can be read by a client.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Thank you for describing your task. Stack Overflow is a **question**-and-**answer** site. The pattern here is that posters, such as yourself, ask questions and other readers answer them. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: You mention that "any client" should be able to connect. Could you narrow that down a bit? Do you mean any web browser, any telnet program, or any client that you specifically wrote for this task?

Comment: well, by any client i actually mean a socket client with another python or maybe ruby script. Not really needing a web browser or anything like that. Poor description on my part. Basically need to be able to share my write_to_viewer() data as a socket stream. Thanks for your help